# how to logivally understand the table.sort function in Lua?

Tags: lua

```
> network = {
>>        {name = "grauna",  IP = "210.26.30.34"},
>>        {name = "arraial", IP = "210.26.30.23"},
>>        {name = "lua",     IP = "210.26.23.12"},
>>        {name = "derain",  IP = "210.26.23.20"},
>>      }
> table.sort(network, function (a,b)
>>       return (a.name > b.name)
>>     end)
>
```

Then, I tried to print out the sorted version of the table elements, as the following.

```
> for i,data in ipairs(network) do
>>   print(index)
>>   for key, value in pairs(data) do
>>      print('\t', key, value)
>>   end
>> end
nil
        IP  210.26.23.12
        name    lua
nil
        IP  210.26.30.34
        name    grauna
nil
        IP  210.26.23.20
        name    derain
nil
        IP  210.26.30.23
        name    arraial
>
```

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? Everything works just fine. Note you are printing `index` (`nil`) not `i`. I suggest looking into [reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/#index) and its article on [`table.sort`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.sort).

Comment: Thanks, I'm continuing reading. And the chapter 6, more about functions help to explain more. I guess I was confused a bit about table.sort.